# Google spreadsheet: check if cell itself is empty

Tags: google-sheets

Is it possible to have a formula somehow on cell A1 that checks as a conditional if A1 is empty?

Obviously, the default way I'm getting a circular dependency error. However, I figure some formula might be (?) smart enough to see that when A1 is in the conditional (and not a part of the new value) it's not really a circular dependency after all.

So does a function like this exist?

Basically: `if cell itself is empty -> fill it, otherwise do nothing`

Comment: Welcome to Web Applications Geert-Jan, I think your question is a duplicate of the one I just added.

Comment: @JacobJanTuinstra: not quite. Given your answer to that question I'm trying to assign `=IF(ISBLANK(A1)=TRUE,"Blank cell","Not blank")` to `A1`. Obviously assigning it to any other cell would work.

Comment: Ok, no dup. but would you accept no for an answer? That's not possible.

Comment: @JacobJanTuinstra: yup I accept it ;) Just wanted to confirm. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For plain old formula's, that's not possible, simply because it will create a *circular dependency*.